# Contact form 7 - madatory fields disabled when not filling them and sending the form

Tags: wordpress

I just realized that in Contact Form 7 my users can't enter anything anymore if they try to send the form but forgot to fill a required field. Typing in the mandatory fields is disabled, only the non-mandatory ones still can be selected.

Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: check to see if u have disabled insted of required... copy and paste your contact form u have created....

Comment: Solved already. Was an issue with conflicting css formatting.